Async gRPC service methods in C#
I am currently trying to find out how to implement async service methods generated based on the proto file, but I am not too sure how to go about doing this.
Is there a virtual asynchronous service method that needs to be overridden? Or do I just need to override the virtual synchronous service method? If it is the latter, do I need to include the use of async and await when overriding the synchronous service method?
How does the generated asynchronous service method work with the generated synchronous service method?
Edit: I am trying to make an asynchronous gRPC call to a server that interacts with a database and then returns some information to me. I then noticed that there is a MyMethodAsync that i can use but it is not a generated virtual method from MyProtoRpc.MyProtoRpcBase and hence cannot be overridden. I was just wondering how MyMethodAsync works and whether or not i should use instead of MyMethod for my use-case.

GrpcService which is generated on the server side only has virtual asynchronous method.
Inherit YourProtoRpc.YourProtoRpcBase.
Within the class body, type override and space.
One of the given options will be YourProtoMethod.
Also, if the virtual method returns Task or Task<TResult> and your overwritten method doesn't await anything.
You should return Task.CompletedTask or Task.FromResult<TResult>().
I'm guessing you are already reading the links below but I will leave it just in case.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/services?view=aspnetcore-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Hi @GorillasPaw, thanks for the response and links!
I don't think i was very clear in my first post, but essentially i am trying to make an asynchronous gRPC call to a server which then interacts with a database and returns some information to me.
I then noticed that there is a generated MyMethodAsync (returns AsyncUnaryCall) that can be called also, but i do not see this as one of the virtual methods that can be overridden (inside MyProtoRpc.MyProtoRpcBase).  How does MyMethodAsync interact with the default MyMethod that can be overridden?

@limzw I see, both methods created for GrpcClient will call the same MyMethod on gRpc server. One without Async on it' s name simply waits the task for you. Also when you call the client method it sends the request, it's not directly calling the method defined on your server as it's defined locally.

i understand now, thanks for helping to clarify!
